# GitHub integration with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, ssh, webhooks

There are multiple approaches in integrating Jenkins with GitHub

Approach 1) Enable ssh communication between GitHub and Jenkins by copying public key file generated in Jenkins to GitHub account. This is one time task.

For any pipeline take  any GitHub url(say `ssh://git@github.com/account/repo.git`) and add using Github plugin for that respective pipeline cocnfiguration

So, Jenkins file just need to have `checkout SCM` to checkout

Approach 2) Enable https communication by adding webhook for every new repo by generating token and enable https comunication between GitHub and Jenkins. But this approach should be repeated for every new repo created in GitHub.

We are using GitHub repo... in production

Which is the best practice of GitHub integration with Jenkins in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are basically two different things.

The first approach lets you set up credentials to checkout and push source code to GitHub using Jenkins. The second approach lets you set up automated build triggers when a change is detected in the repository.

In summary, the first is mandatory for a build to get the source code, while the second is optional as you can trigger builds manually as well, although automated triggers on code push are inherent to continuous integration. Also, you need not add webhooks individually for every repository. Rather, add it once at the organization level to have all the repositories in that organization covered including any new additions.

Comment: I think you're right.. but second approach need webhook configuration for every repo. Isn't it?

Comment: Can webhook trigger be enabled automatically for any new repo added?  In GitHub...

Comment: @overexchange Yes, if you add the webhook at the organization level (under https://github.com/[organization] > **Settings** > **Hooks**), all existing repositories and new repositories added to the organization in future will automatically get covered by GitHub for webhook deliveries.

Comment: I haven't worked with Gitlab so far, so won't be able to comment on this part. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are talking about an on-premise GitHub Enterprise, you also have an alternative approach with [GitHub Action](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/about-github-actions).

- Either by using the [built-in CI/CD](https://github.com/features/actions), which does include an [embedded Jenkins Single-shot](https://schd.ws/hosted_files/devopsworldjenkinsworld2018/8f/DWJW2018%20-%20A%20Cloud%20Native%20Jenkins.pdf) (slide 42).

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1872314/47345918-3b280e80-d6ac-11e8-9f44-8cc02754f691.png]

- Or with [`appleboy/jenkins-action`](https://github.com/appleboy/jenkins-action), a GitHub Action that trigger Jenkins jobs.
  That way, you call your own Jenkins server, but without having to declare a webhook and implement a listener for said webhook.

That is:

```
name: trigger jenkins job
on: [push]
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: trigger single Job
      uses: appleboy/jenkins-action@master
      with:
        url: "http://example.com"
        user: "example"
        token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
        job: "foobar"
```

Comment: Some teams are maintain ing  private repo in GitHub and some Enterprise license